# Display contents of file as binary

Tags: file, binary

Is there a good way to display the contents of a file as binary?

I am creating a program that needs to save and load a 2D arrays from a files.
When loading a saved file the result appears different.
I need to be able to view the contents of the saved file in plain binary to tell if my problem in in my save or load function.

Is there a program like octal dump but is binary dump?

Thanks.

Comment: @Dave - ?? how is this not programming related?

Comment: @Eric - you might get better results if you specify what platform/language your are dealing with.

Comment: The reason why it "appears different" is most probably an encoding problem.

Answer (score 4):

On linux/unix (or Windows + cygwin) there is the "od" utility which dumps files in many formats.

E.g. hexadecimal:

od -t x1 file...

I hope it may help you.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, using Ruby from the command line:

```
cat file | ruby -e "puts STDIN.read.unpack('B*')[0].scan(/[01]{8}/).join(' ')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Having the raw binary dump is too overwhelming for most people. Consider using `od -x`, or if you need a more specific format then examine the various options for `-t`.